# node-sass install failing on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to run Gulp but it keeps failing while attempting to install node-sass (a dependency of the gulp-sass plugin).

The issue seems to be that node is not finding a script file during install. I verified that script does actually exist in the project repository. When I pull my repo locally on the server and install it, it installs without a problem. That makes me think it's a Jenkins related environment issue.

Here's the error output:

```
> node-sass@2.1.1 install /root/.jenkins/jobs/odyssey-frontend/workspace/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/root/.jenkins/jobs/odyssey-frontend/workspace/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
npm ERR! Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/ec2-user/.linuxbrew/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@2.1.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@2.1.1 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/.jenkins/jobs/odyssey-frontend/workspace/npm-debug.log
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.jenkins/jobs/odyssey-frontend/workspace/gulpfile.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Linux distribution is Amazon Linux AMI, Fedora-like. Trying to install node-sass ^2.0.1 via gulp-sass ^1.3.3.

I just tried the updated gulp-sass 2.0.0 with node-sass 3.0.0 and still have the same issue.

I removed all node-sass dependencies and it builds successfully now. So its really just that package; all other node packages install successfully.

Comment: can you also run `echo $NODE_PATH` within the same job? Probably you have not set it globally. And for Jenkins it doesn't make sense if it setted for the user.

Comment: It echoed out empty. What purpose does $NODE_PATH serve?

Comment: I added a NODE_PATH environment variable via the Jenkins system configuration interface that points to the same locations it does when I echo it in bash. Still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this on the Github project where it was answered: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/941#issuecomment-100414516

Jenkins seems to run everything as sudo when building. NPM, as a security feature, won't run install scripts as sudo, hence the error. Adding a `--unsafe-perm` flag to the install script gets by this issue.